# How to disable ScrollView Bounce In SwiftUI

Tags: scrollview, swiftui, bounce

Any `Modifier` available to stop bounce of `ScrollView` in `swiftUI` ?

```
struct RoomDetailsView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            Image("test")
            Text("Hello Text")
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I tried below code but it not work for me. looks like it deprecated

```
ScrollView(alwaysBounceVertical: true) {
       Image("test")
       Text("Hello Text")
       ...
       ...
}
```

Comment: hmm.. I don't observe any bounce in the described scenario. So do you want to "stop" or to "add", because in second block of code it seems you try to enable it, however in question to disable it.

Comment: I want to stop bounce in scrollview. earlier second block is working. but now I'm not found right now any solution for that my  current code is looks like first block.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: not able to find solution

Comment: For the case of static content inside ScrollView it can be used solution from [SwiftUI: Make ScrollView scrollable only if it exceeds the height of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466397/12299030). It is not applicable for active content, because based on `.disabled` modifier.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

try using this line of code:

```
UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
```

You can use it like this:-

```
struct RoomDetailsView: View {
   init() {
      UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
   }

   var body: some View {
      ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
         Image("test")
         Text("Hello Text")
         ...
         ...
          }
      }
  }
```

Or you can write this line in AppDelegate to apply this behaviour throughout into your app.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
 }
```

Comment: doesnt the first one change all scrollviews in my app too?

Comment: Yup, @DiNerd the first will eventually change the appearance throughout the application, and this is the actual statement, below ones are just its implementation example.
You can use any of the below two ways to achieve it.

Comment: If you only want to disable bouncing if the content is smaller than the scrollview size, do this: `UIScrollView.appearance().alwaysBounceVertical = false`

Comment: WARNING: This caused bugs with our UIPageViewControllers. Apparently, they need bounces = true to work properly. Make sure you put it back to true to avoid breaking that class.

Answer (score 14):

1. Set the ScrollView's showsIndicators parameter equal to false so the user interacting with your view doesn't activate the scroll indicator (it can happen even without scrolling enabled).

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false)
```

2. In the onAppear modifier for the ScrollView, add this line.

```
UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
```

3. In the onDisappear modifier for the ScrollView, add this line.

```
UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = true
```

If you set UIScrollView.appearance().bounces equal to false in the init, it will prevent all of your app's ScrollViews from bouncing. By setting it equal to true in the onAppear modifier and equal to false in the onDisappear modifier, you ensure that it only effects the one ScrollView.

Your ScrollView should look something like this.

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
.onAppear {
    UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
}
.onDisappear {
    UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = true
}
```

Comment: it will take effect it's child view. I have nested scrollview and only parent view need to be forbidden bouncing, anyone can help? on iOS 15

Answer (score 12):

Apple introduced an new modifier named `scrollBounceBehavior` with iOS 16.4 that can be used to prevent the ScrollView from bouncing when the content is smaller than the screen.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrollbouncebehavior(_:axes:)

```
struct RoomDetailsView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            Image("test")
            Text("Hello Text")
            ...
            ...
        }
        .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost there... Now we just need a way to disable it, unconditionally.

Comment: Nice answer! SwiftUI getting better and better.

Comment: Honestly do not understand the SwiftUI team sometimes..

Comment: Apple has spoken, thou shall not not bounce

Answer (score 6):

You may use [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect.git) library:

```swift
ScrollView {
    // some content
}
.introspectScrollView { scrollView in
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
}
```

Comment: Tried this now. Already added the library. Value of type 'ScrollView<some View>' has no member 'introspectScrollView'

Comment: did you add import?

"import Introspect"

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(

Comment: replace 
"scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false"
 
with -> "scrollView.bounces = false"

Answer (score 2):

I have created a small *ViewModifier* in order to disable scrolling bounces **only** in **specific** Views:

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
  func disableBounces() -> some View {
    modifier(DisableBouncesModifier())
  }
}

struct DisableBouncesModifier: ViewModifier {
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .onAppear {
        UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
      }
      .onDisappear {
        UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = true
      }
  }
}
```

Then you can simply call it on your views as any normal viewModifier

```
// Your view definition... 
.disableBounces()
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to use viewbuilder and create your own scrollview that doesn't bounce when the content size is less than scrollview frame size.

```
import SwiftUI

struct BounceVerticalDisableScrollView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @State private var alwaysBounceVertical = false
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { scrlViewGeometry in
            ScrollView {
                content
                    .background(
                        GeometryReader {
                            // calculate height by clear background
                            Color.clear.preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self,
                                                   value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                        }.onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) {
                            self.alwaysBounceVertical = $0 < scrlViewGeometry.size.height
                        }
                    )
            }
            // disable scroll when content size is less than frame of scrollview
            .disabled(self.alwaysBounceVertical)
        }
    }
}
// return size
public struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    public static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero
    
    public static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

So, that you can use the scrollview as:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            BounceVerticalDisableScrollView{
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 10)  {
                   ....
                   .... 
                }.padding()
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the same behavior. It still bounced.

Comment: I think you may want to just return `nextValue()` in the size preference reduce function right? If you add it to the existing value then it's going to keep getting bigger with every layout change, rather than simply reflecting the most recent content height. I'm assuming that's what caused @chitgoks issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the available options aren't great as they aren't backwards compatible and tend to completely disable scrolling.

A workaround is to add height to your scrollview.