# SwiftUI: ScrollView that drags bottom sheet with it

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-scrollview, draggesture

I'm trying to create a SwiftUI Scrollview that drags its container like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O92DgsVI1OjM1HEUXUwVywB8gcdShOP-/view?usp=sharing

Many Apple apps use this (Apple Maps, Music, Wallet, etc) but I haven't found an easy way to do it wit SwiftUI. What do you think is the best way to implement this simply?

I've looked at most libraries here https://github.com/search?q=swiftui+drawer but none of them implements their drawer with a ScrollView in it that can drag the view.

I also tried implementing a custom UIScrollView as UIViewRepresentable and I tried to tweak the scrollViewWillBeginDragging() but I could not make it work.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem, did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I ran into this problem while developing a [drawer package](https://github.com/bwide/SwiftUI-Drawer) myself, and I believe I was able to solve it using the legacy `UIscrollView` and a `UIViewRepresentable` wrapper.

if you want to use the packages you already had before, here's I ended up doing:

inside my Drawer, I've added this [LegacyScrollView](https://github.com/bwide/LegacyScrollView) wrapper.

```swift
    LegacyScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: showsIndicators) {
        content
    }
    .onDragShouldBegin { pan, scrollView in
        /// touch shouldn't begin when scrolling past zero content offset
        scrollView.contentOffset.y - pan.translation(in: scrollView).y > 0
    }
```

with this wrapper I'm able to access UIScrollView's `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)` and override it through a SwiftUI modifier

[Result](https://github.com/bwide/SwiftUI-Drawer/blob/main/Media/DrawerScrollableContent.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Following is used to apply throughout the application

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution for a SwiftUI ScrollView, not a UIScrollView.

Comment: @blrsk Please go through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799474/how-to-disable-scrollview-bounce-in-swiftui

Comment: Above code also work. but this is for throughout the app.

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issue and came across the [FloatingPanel](https://github.com/scenee/FloatingPanel) package. The repo includes an [example](https://github.com/scenee/FloatingPanel/tree/master/Examples/Maps-SwiftUI) to apply it to SwiftUI apps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It looks promising. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [SheeKit](https://github.com/edudnyk/SheeKit) library where that behaviour is supported for native sheets.

You can read about the implementation [in this story](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/customise-and-resize-sheets-in-swiftui-df9fae7c369b) on medium. Also, you can find the demo video in the end of the story.

In case if you need an advanced native SwiftUI scroll view with the support of content offset tracking and other UIKit-like configurability, check the [SolidScroll](https://github.com/edudnyk/SolidScroll) library and the [story](https://medium.com/@eugenedudnyk/swiftui-scroll-like-in-uikit-using-only-swiftui-hidden-apis-8af2be0534c7) behind it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It looks promising. I'll take a look.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            DraggableView()
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    Text("Hello World")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me

Comment: Above code is working at my end. I think there is issue in DraggableView(). Please comment that code as of now and then check.

Comment: I updated the question with the whole file.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! Would be nice with an explanation of your answer and not just code.

Comment: This does not work. There is no valid answer yet