# Keep DragGesture working over list or scrollview SwiftUI in custom draggable sheet

Tags: swift, xcode, list, swiftui, scrollview

I'm making SwiftUI package to display custom Sheet at quarter, half and full screen.
I achieved the partial sheet and make It draggable.
The problem is when Sheet contains scrollable content like List or ScrollView.

#### For exemple for usage without scrollable content like this :

```
ZStack {
                Color.blue
                YLFlexSheet(sheetMode: $sheetMode, draggable: true){
                    Color.black
                }
            }
```

It works like that :

[image]

#### With scrollable content in sheet :

```
ZStack {
                Color.blue
                YLFlexSheet(sheetMode: $sheetMode, draggable: true){
                    List{
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]

#### YLFlexSheet

```
public struct YLFlexSheet<Content: View>: View {
    
    @State private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    
    private let content: () -> Content
    private let draggable: Bool
    @Binding private var sheetMode: YLSheetMode
    
    public init(sheetMode: Binding<YLSheetMode>,
                draggable: Bool = false,
                @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self._sheetMode = sheetMode
        self.draggable = draggable
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Group {
            if draggable {
                content()
                    .onTapGesture { }
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 30, coordinateSpace: .local)
                            .onChanged { value in
                                dragOffset = value.translation
                            }
                            .onEnded{ value in
                                dragOffset = .zero
                                updateMode(translationHeight: value.translation.height)
                            }
                    )
            }else{
                content()
            }
        }
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .offset(y: offSet > 0 ? offSet : 0)
        .animation(.spring())
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

I'm looking for way of keeping the content scrollable if needed. Do you have an idea how to manage both scrollable content and the DragGesture of the sheet.

Like this :

[image]

I try some thing like `minimumDistance`on DragGesture, `onTap` and `highPriorityGesture` without success.

Comment: I've answered this in a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71166212/8041103