# SwiftUI TabView prevent swipe bounce

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have a TabView with `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())`

I am trying to prevent the first view and last view from bouncing. So basically, prevent scrolling horizontally.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var stop = false
    var body: some View {
        TabView {

            Text("Example 1")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    // read and store origin (min X) of page
                    Color.red.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                                         value: $0.frame(in: .global).minX)
                }).contentShape(Rectangle())

            Text("Example 2")
            Text("Example 3")

        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
            
            if $0 > 0.0 {
                // Off screen stop scrolling horizontal
                print("off screen")
                stop = true
            } else {
                stop = false
            }

            print("Offset >> \($0)")
        }.gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10)
              .onEnded { value in
                print(value)
              }
              .onChanged { value in
               print(value)
              }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to disable ScrollView Bounce In SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59897811/17771995) May this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to add below line in **.onAppear** Method.

```
.onAppear(perform: {
            UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
        })
```

**Here is the full code.**

struct ContentView: View {

```
@State var stop = false
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Text("Example 1")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(GeometryReader {
                // read and store origin (min X) of page
                Color.red.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                                     value: $0.frame(in: .global).minX)
            }).contentShape(Rectangle())
        
        Text("Example 2")
        Text("Example 3")
    }
    .onAppear(perform: {
        UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
    })
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
        
        if $0 > 0.0 {
            // Off screen stop scrolling horizontal
            print("off screen")
            stop = true
        } else {
            stop = false
        }
        
        print("Offset >> \($0)")
    }.gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10)
            .onEnded { value in
                print(value)
            }
            .onChanged { value in
                print(value)
            }
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any way to apply this to the tab view scroll view only? this seems to disable all scrollviews